# Unable to load the gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I created a gem with a name 'my_gem'. I use this in my Gemfile as like

```
gem 'my_gem' path: "/home/user/project" #git: "git@bitbucket.org:Teamlaunch/launch-service-app.git", branch: "master"
```

I am able to build the gem. I also can install this gem with "bundle install" command. But When I run this through rails console it can not identify the gem

```
 $rails c
 2.1.0 :007 >   require 'my_gem'
 LoadError: cannot load such file -- my_gem
```

Comment: What is your gem structure? Are you sure your gem library is named as gem itself?

Comment: @MarekLipka - Can you add this in answer part? Its working after correcting gem name

Comment: it's done. Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have your library named differently than a gem. So check how is your library named and change argument for `require` respectively.